# Use several "criterias" for SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel-formula

I manage to sum all values based on one (1) criteria ("SIGN-") according to the following formula:

=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SIGN-";'1. Data'!$C:$C));'1. Data'!D:D)

This is based on the formula looking for the "SIGN-"-text in only one (1) column. Now, I would like the formula to also look for a certain text in column E in the '1. Data' tab.

I.e. I would like the formula to sum all values in column D as long as column C starts with the word "SIGN-" and column E="2017-12".

Have been trying to add the AND function to several places in the formula but I don´t manage to make it work.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: You don;t use the `AND()` function in conjunction with `SUMPRODUCT()` ti tends to wrok in the form of TRUE = 1 FALSE = 0, so you multiply each condition and if a row fails on any point, it is multiplied by 0 and so 0 is summed...

Comment: Your formula as it is looks for SIGN- anywhere in the text and not just starting.  _A-SIGN-OF-THE-TIMES_ would be included in the sum for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your input! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
= SUMPRODUCT('1. Data'!D:D;(LEFT('1. Data'!C:C;5)="SIGN-")+0;('1. Data'!E:E="2017-12")+0)
```

The preferred solution would be to use `SUMIFS` but since the `C` column criteria is a bit trickier, the easier-to-use formula is with `SUMPRODUCT` even though it is not as efficient. That being said, it is recommended to reduce these full column references only to the end of the data. E.g. if you have 100 rows of data, change `D:D` to `D1:D100`, etc.

Comment: @norden22 Please mark my answer as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.